# display a variable before assignment

Tags: variable

How can I display a variable at the beginning of a document, when the variable is assigned later in the document ?

I want to use `\myVar{}` here, but the assignment is later : `\def \myVar {some text}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.StackExchange! Please, always show not only a code snippet but a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964). This would help us to help you.